# Fantastic Beasts and Where to Tag Them

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently we have a tag for "Fantastic Beasts" [fantastic-beasts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fantastic-beasts) whose wiki reads:

> Use this tag to refer to the fictional book called 'Fantastic Beasts and Where To Find Them', the 2016 film of the same name, or the five-movie franchise it began. Use this tag with the [harry-potter] tag.

I find this very confusing and not fitting with our tagging conventions (especially when it comes to new works and ignoring tags due to spoilers).

Therefore I propose that we split the original book and film into two separate tags. I see two pretty straight forward options, which I have added as answers below.

I have added my two options to be voted on accordingly. Feel free to add other options if you have a different idea.

I prefer option 2 as it gives a greater level of clarity with 5 films coming out that will share the "Fantastic Beasts" prefix.

Comment: What about [tag:movie]?  Should we use that, or is the franchise now too big?

Comment: @Kevin Why would [[tag:movie]] be useful here?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot: If we only had the movie and the book, then that's what [tag:movie] is for.  But since we've got the other films, I suspect it would become unworkable.

Comment: @Kevin Oh so you mean [[tag:fantastic-beasts]] for the fictional book and [[tag:fantastic-beasts]][[tag:movie]] for the film series?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot: Yeah, but I don't think that would actually solve Skooba's problem (of not wanting to see spoilers for the *new* films in particular) so I haven't proposed it.

Comment: @Kevin To be honest I don't like that solution even disregarding the spoilers for new films problem. Especially as we have ways to name different tags here without needing to do that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Option 3**

- [fantastic-beasts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fantastic-beasts) For the franchise
- [fantastic-beasts-where-to-find-them](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fantastic-beasts-where-to-find-them) For the film, it names the film in full (minus the word "and", which would exceed the 35 character limit for tag names)

I don't think we need a tag for the fictional book; a quick search of [questions tagged [fantastic-beasts] from before 2016](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bfantastic-beasts%5D+is%3Aq+created%3A2005..2015) yields only 3 questions with only 1 about the fictional book. Widening that search for [`[harry-potter] fantastic beasts is:q created:2005..2015`](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bharry-potter%5D+fantastic+beasts+is%3Aq+created%3A2005..2015) returns 17 results and a quick leaf through shows only 2 or 3 of them are really about the fictional book.

Comment: So the source material is just a by-prodcut :P

Comment: Since we have the characters, why can't the franchise be [fantastic-beasts-franchise]?

Comment: @eshier -franchise suffix's are frowned upon if I remember rightly and if there's a way to name it without it, which there surely is here, we should always prefer that.

Comment: I don't see how naming the film in full matters considering 4/5 will include subtitles or alternate name, presuming all 5 get made. Additionally, I think that you could work in something with Wizarding World, as that's what the HP universe is now being officially marketed as.

Comment: @WebHead naming the film in full should be preferred to a partial name and year suffix in my opinion.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot the problem I have with naming the film in full is that regardless of the number of questions, the book came first. It should have naming rights because if the character space had been available when it was created it would/should have been used.

Comment: @Skooba I'd agree with you if 1) there was a use case for the book and 2) the book was more popular. The more popular tag should always, in my opinion, have rights to the more accurate tag name.

Comment: So what is the more accurate tag for The Crimes of Grindewald?

Comment: @WebHead The name is in two parts so either [tag:the-crimes-of-grindelwald] or [tag:fantastic-beasts-the-crimes-of-grindelwald] should be fine, assuming the latter is short enough I didn't check. Whereas FBaWtFT is one full name and [tag:where-to-find-them] wouldn't be the best tag even if it wasn't.

Comment: The full name for TCoG is too long for a tag I just checked...

Comment: @Skooba The source material is like 30 pages and not at all a 'basis' for the movies. It's just a dozen or so monsters and their descriptions (literally a cutesy real-life adaptation of an in-universe school textbook). So, yes, it's just a by-product :-)

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Looks like there is enough for a consensus here. I guess the next step would be to implement it.

Comment: @Skooba Yup, drip feed them over a few weeks or so. I have created the tag so we can make a start when needed.

Answer (score 2):

**Option 2**

- Create a new tag [fantastic-beasts-2016](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fantastic-beasts-2016) for the film
- Create a new tag [fantastic-beasts-where-to-find-them](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fantastic-beasts-where-to-find-them) for the book
- Use the original tag as a franchise tag.

Answer (score -6):

**Option 1**

- Create a new tag [fantastic-beasts-2016](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fantastic-beasts-2016) for the film
- Rewrite the original tag wiki to refer to only the book